# In Google sheets, I have 3 cells with percentage. I want to make dynamic all 3 cells on each other

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I have 3 cells.
If I changes one cell value then other 3 cells are change automatically.

Suppose I have 100 percentage for 3 cells.
If I enter 30% in 1st cell.
So,other 2 cells divide into remaining percentage.

How can I implement this?

Comment: please provide a sample worksheet with data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.